# How to fix "curved" raster tiff transformed from hdf to a suitable raster in R?

Tags: r, gdal

I'm working with MODIS Atmosphere product like MOD35, I read that is better convert hdf to geotiff and be able to work it in any software GIS. I did the following:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(gdalUtils)

setwd("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Documents")
filename = "MOD35_L2.A2017003.1520.061.2017311220101.hdf"
#print(filename)

sds = get_subdatasets(filename)
#print(sds)
gdal_translate(sds[7], dst_dataset = "mascara_nubes.tif", b = 1) #sds[7] is cloud_mask sds

gdalwarp("mascara_nubes.tif", "mascara_nubes_projec.tif", 
         s_srs = "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs",
         t_srs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs", r = "near", overwrite = T)
```

and I got this result:

[image: Result of the code I made]

As seen in the image, it looks like curved.

The expected result is this, which was generated with the ENVI

[image: ENVI result]

I would like to know what I did wrong or what I need to add to get the same result of ENVI in R.
I'm new in this community and I will be grateful for your help

Comment: They both look "curved" to me.  Seems likely that you are applying an incorect projection.  I'm pretty sure the raw MODIS data is already in lat-long (wgs84) coordinates - see here https://modis-atmosphere.gsfc.nasa.gov/products/cloud-mask/format-content.  So projecting it from sinusoidal into lat-lng could be the error.  Perhaps you have `s_srs` and `t_srs` the wrong way around?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, maybe in the images you do not notice very well. Seen from profile, in the image I got with R it looks like this:   ∩   and in the made with ENVI it looks like this:   __   .So my doubt was that, how can I get an image with a projection like this  __  .Where I have to fix?